# How to get all definitions in an ApplicationDomain of a loaded SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When you load a SWF into another, the loader SWF can get specific definitions from the loaded SWF using `ApplicationDomain.getDefinition(name:String)`. For example:

```js
package 
{
    // ... imports

    public class SWFLoader extends Sprite
    {
        private var loadedAppDomain:ApplicationDomain;

        public function SWFLoader()
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.swf");
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onTestLoadComplete);
            loader.load(request);
        }

        private function onTestLoadComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
            loadedAppDomain = loaderInfo.applicationDomain;

            // Here we can get ANY defined symbol (class, namespace or function according to Adobe Flash help)
            var someSymbolClass:Class = Class(loadedAppDomain.getDefinition("SomeSymbol"));
            var someSymbolSprite:Sprite = Sprite(new someSymbolClass());

            addChild(sprite);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get all of the definitions in a SWF, without specifying each explicitly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Flash Player 11.3, you can use `ApplicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames()`.

See [the official documentation for the method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getQualifiedDefinitionNames) and [this blog post about the Flash Player release](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3705).

Comment: Beautiful. At last Adobe added this functionality :)

Comment: As of 3/31/2014, the method is not actually documented.  There is no mention of `getQualifiedDefinitionNames` at the documentation link for ApplicationDomain.  The method does, however, work, and it returns a `Vector.<String>` of the classes defined in that particular ApplicationDomain.  Also note that it doesn't return definitions of parent domains, even though getDefinition/hasDefinition will return true for classes defined in parent domains.

Comment: It is documented there but you need to set the player version to 11.3 or above to see it.  Up the top under the page title.

Comment: @GlenBlanchard +1 for introducing me to the filters! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** This is the quickest solution to your problem : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=175

Hi, you could use this library : https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/
Don't have the time to do deeper test, but here is what i found :

1 - I have created a .swf containing in the library 2 exported MC, $Test and $Test2
2 - Once the .swf loaded by a Loader, i run this code :

```
var swf : SWF = new SWF(loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes);
trace(swf);
```

3 - In the output you'll notice theses lines :

```
[76:SymbolClass] 
  Symbols:
    [0] TagID: 2, Name: $Test2
    [1] TagID: 1, Name: $Test
```

I think that there is a way to obtain this info directly thru the library API

Comment: Excellent, I will use SWFExplorer Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the loaded SWF in the current ApplicationDomain.

Use ApplicationDomain.currentDomain to do that, on the ContextLoader info.

```
loader.load(request, new ContextLoader(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
```

It should work.

Comment: And then what? I have access to all classes, namespaces and functions of the loaded SWF? can I run: `var someSymbolSprite:Sprite = Sprite(new SomeSymbol())`?

Comment: Yes, you can access every symbol in the loaded swf, just as if they was declared in the current movie.

Answer (score -1):

Following from the answer I received from a previous question I asked here a few days ago (it's about SWC , but in your case, it doesn't really make a difference )
[Working with SWCs - getDefinitionByName issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103641/working-with-swcs-getdefinitionbyname-issue)

If both SWFs share the same ApplicationDomain, you should be able to access the loaded SWF classes directly by doing this:

```
//provided that SomeSymbol extends Sprite...
var someSymbolSprite:Sprite =new SomeSymbol();
```

On the other hand, you won't be able to do this

```
var SomeSymbol:Class = getDefinitionByName("SomeSymbol");
```

unless you create a library of objects from the loaded SWF

```
var ssym:SomeSymbol;
```

Check the above link for more details.

Comment: But that's the same of the example, I have to know that the symbol `SomeSymbol` exists. I want a list of all symbols without hardcoding everyone.