# Get Class by string from swc

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got several Movieclips from Flash that I'm embedding in a swc. I've got the swc included in my Flash Builder project and am able to use the classes just fine.

The problem I have is that I'm creating a function that grabs a specific movieclip by number (named FX01 through FX05) and I want to get these classes by using an int. I want to avoid a set of if statements, and I've run into this problem before, but settled for the aforementioned if statements. So, for future reference, I'd like to learn how to do this.

I want to essentially do something similar to `this["myVar" + i.toString];` except for the swc classes

I've tried `getDefinitionByName("FX01")` but I get the error `ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable FX01 is not defined.` which leads me to believe I'm using it incorrectly. Here is what I have so far

```
public var powerupFXType:int = 1;
state function powerupFX_onStart():void 
{   
    fx.usingMovieClip(getDefinitionByName("FX01"), 30).attach(); //this line doesn't work
    fx.usingMovieClip(FX01, 30).attach(); //this line works
    fx.usingMovieClip(getDefinitionByName("FX0" + powerupFXType.toString()), 30).attach(); //this is what I want the line to look like
}
```

Also note: the state function is something of our own design and it cannot take parameters in it, so I must hold the type outside.

Comment: What is the fully qualified class name of `FX01`?  eg what does the first line in it say?  `package {` ? or `package myPath {`  etc.

Comment: Also, you need to cast the result as `Class`:   `fx.usingMovieClip(flash.utils.getDefinitionByName("FX01") as Class, 30).attach()`

Comment: @Batman I am unsure, I can't view the source. It was published by Flash. The MovieClip is exported for Actionscript under the class name FX01. It's base class is a MovieClip

Comment: do you have to have an Import to use it? If so the import will tell you the fully qualified path.  For instance, if it was a MovieClip, you'd use:  `getDefinitionByName("flash.display.MovieClip") as Class`

Comment: No import in the class I'm working with, It's coming straight from the swc file, added in my library path in my build path for my project preferences

Comment: Well, just to confirm, try going the other directions and trace out the results of `getQualifiedClassName(FX01)`

Comment: `getQualifiedClassName(FX01)` traces out as `FX01`

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103641/working-with-swcs-getdefinitionbyname-issue?rq=1

Comment: Basically you just add this compiler argument to make sure all classes in the swc get included: `-include-libraries`